# On a four-week struggle for a functional LINQ LAMBDA expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been trying to find the correct LINQ LAMBDA expression for the last month, with zero successful results.

I cannot use the following tools:

- Linqer is unable to run because the Microsoft tool it uses to create the SQL connection (the dbml file) refuses to install on my Win8.1 system
- LinqPad doesn’t provide an actual translation until you actually buy the product (which makes the “trial” fundamentally broken in the first place)

I have three levels of tables that I need to bring back into a single viewmodel.

- Level one is a company table. Easy as s**t.
- Level two is a "cycle" table. This is where I have gotten hung up on, since many cycles can exist for a company, but I need to grab only the latest cycle by date.
- Level three is a pair of tables that exist off the cycle, I only need a true/false test for content in those tables for the cycle in question. I haven't even *tried* this yet.

So far I have come up with a minimally functional SQL script (that only deals with the first two levels), but my MVC project is making use of several tools that hook straight into LAMBDA expressions, including PagedList. I need a LAMBDA expression and not a pure SQL expression.

My SQL:

```
SELECT 
      co.CompanyId
    , co.CompanyName
    , co.CompanyCity
    , co.NumberOfEmployees
    , co.ProspectingScore
    , cd.PDFResourceLibrary
    , cd.PresentationDone
    , cd.MOUDone
FROM Company AS co 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
          TOP 1 MAX(CycleDate) AS CycleDate
        , PDFResourceLibrary
        , PresentationDone
        , MOUDone 
    FROM Cycle AS cy
    WHERE cy.CompanyId = co.CompanyId 
    GROUP BY PDFResourceLibrary, PresentationDone, MOUDone
) AS cd 
ORDER BY co.ProspectingScore DESC
```

I have tried a number of lambda expressions to date:

```
db.Company
  .GroupJoin(
      db.Cycle
    , co => co.CompanyId
    , cy => cy.CycleId
    , (x, y) => new { Company = x, Cycle = y }
  ).Select(
    y => y.Cycle.OrderByDescending(y => y.CycleDate).SingleOrDefault()
  ).ToList();
```

But this throws a `local variable cannot have the same name as a method type parameter` as well as a `Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` error.

Converting it to a `Join` flags the `OrderByDescending` as invalid, but I need that to drop all but the most latest cycle.

I also can't seem to do a join to save my effin' life. All the examples out there fail with my system.

For example, a join that comes sooooooo close is:

```
db.Company.Join(
    db.Cycle.OrderByDescending(x => x.CycleDate).SingleOrDefault()
  , co => co.CompanyId
  , cy => cy.CycleId
  , (x, y) => new { Company = x, Cycle = y }
).ToList();
```

but then it claims `The type arguments for method Queryable Join cannot be inferred from the usage`. Like, --what??

I have also tried the following:

```
db.Company.Include(
  x => x.Cycle.OrderByDescending(y => y.CycleDate).SingleOrDefault()
).ToList();
```

which *works for the company* but I cannot seem to drill past the company and into the cycle, when I go, `@(item.Cycle.PresentationDone` it says that `ICollection<Cycle> does not contain a definition for PresentationDone`, even though I have an ICollection for Cycle in my Company model. It's right there, but the system won’t see it to follow.

An attempt with

```
db.Company.Select(x => new { Company = x, Cycle = x.Cycle.OrderByDescending(y => y.CycleDate).Single() }).ToList();
```

also throws the List to IEnumerable conversion error.

As a final note, please keep in mind that I am bringing two models into the same page, and the second model is the same as the first but focuses only on the company. *IT* works. It has no problem pulling data out of the DB:

```
viewModel.AllCompanies = db.Company.ToList();
```

Because it does not need to pull anything from the cycle -- I am ignoring anything beneath the Company level. But for the first query, I have to bring several items off of the cycle, and so I need to query for the most recent cycle.

---

**EDIT:**

With the generous assistance of [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) I have assembled the following:

```
var query = (IPagedList<DashboardUserData>)(
  from co in db.Company
  join cy in db.Cycle on co.CompanyId equals cy.CycleId into cycles
  from cd in cycles.OrderByDescending(cy => cy.CycleDate).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
  orderby co.ProspectingScore descending
  select new {
    CompanyId = co.CompanyId,
    CompanyName = co.CompanyName,
    CompanyCity = co.CompanyCity,
    NumberOfEmployees = co.NumberOfEmployees,
    ProspectingScore = co.ProspectingScore,
    PDFResourceLibrary = (bool?)cd.PDFResourceLibrary,
    PresentationDone = (bool?)cd.PresentationDone,
    MOUDone = (bool?)cd.MOUDone
  }).ToPagedList(regionPageIndex, pageSize);
```

And my model is such:

```
public IPagedList<DashboardUserData> RegionalCompanies { get; set; }
public class DashboardUserData {
  public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
  public int? NumberOfEmployees { get; set; }
  public int? ProspectingScore { get; set; }
  public bool? PDFResourceLibrary { get; set; }
  public bool? PresentationDone { get; set; }
  public bool? MOUDone { get; set; }
}
```

But for some reason I am unable to attach the data to the model. I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`8[System.Guid,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]]]' to type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[CCS.Models.DashboardUserData]'.
```

It's probably something stupidly simple, but I'm missing it.

---

**EDIT 2:**

When I add a filter to the original table, Company:

```
var query = (IPagedList<DashboardUserData>)(
  from co in db.Company
  where co.RegionId == new Guid(User.GetClaimValue("Region"))
```

I now get an issue of:

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities
```

Still have that model issue from the first Edit, tho.

---

**Edit 3:**

Huh, I may have solved Edit 1:

```
viewModel.RegionalCompanies = (
  from co in db.Company
  where co.RegionId == regionId
  join cy in db.Cycle on co.CompanyId equals cy.CycleId into cycles
  from cd in cycles.OrderByDescending(cy => cy.CycleDate).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
  orderby co.ProspectingScore descending
  select new DashboardUserData {
    CompanyId = co.CompanyId,
    CompanyName = co.CompanyName,
    CompanyCity = co.CompanyCity,
    NumberOfEmployees = co.NumberOfEmployees,
    ProspectingScore = co.ProspectingScore,
    PDFResourceLibrary = cd.PDFResourceLibrary,
    PresentationDone = cd.PresentationDone,
    MOUDone = cd.MOUDone
  }).ToPagedList(regionPageIndex, pageSize);
```

But now the second viewModel:

```
viewModel.AllOtherCompanies = await db.Company.Where(c => c.RegionId != regionId).Include(c => c.Province).ToPagedListAsync(allPageIndex, pageSize);
return View(viewModel);
```

Is throwing one very confusing error message:

```
The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.
```

which I have never seen before, even with the original code. Googling right now.

---

**Edit 4:**

OMFG, I think I have it working. I was concentrating on getting the first model to work properly with `IPagedList`, and forgot that `IPagedList` requires an order in order to page properly. This is coming once I get column sorting and paging implemented on the page side and the correct code in the controller, but once I stuck in a temporary `.OrderBy()` in the second viewModel, everything suddenly stood up properly.

A big shout-out to [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev), your reply was a massive kick in the right direction!! Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please provide the basic C# class definitions that you're working with? If you can also provide source sample data that would be great.

Comment: So if you remove the `ToPagedList` part at the end, it works fine?

Comment: Why on earth are you struggling four weeks with a LINQ statement when you got a working SQL statement? Writing an ADO.NET solution would take one hour. You can mix tools you know? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you when working with complex queries, to use the LINQ query syntax for the most parts of the query because it's much easier to follow and modify due to the transparent identifiers. Also it maps more natively to the SQL query.

For instance, here is the LINQ equivalent of your SQL query:

```
var query =
    from co in db.Company
    from cd in (
        from cy in db.Cycle
        where cy.CompanyId == co.CompanyId
        group cy by new { cy.PDFResourceLibrary, cy.PresentationDone, cy.MOUDone } into g
        select new
        {
            CycleDate = g.Max(cy => cy.CycleDate),
            g.Key.PDFResourceLibrary,
            g.Key.PresentationDone,
            g.Key.MOUDone
        }
    )
    .OrderByDescending(cy => cy.CycleDate).Take(1) // TOP 1
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // OUTER
    orderby co.ProspectingScore descending
    select new
    {
        co.CompanyId,
        co.CompanyName,
        co.CompanyCity,
        co.NumberOfEmployees,
        co.ProspectingScore,
        cd.PDFResourceLibrary,
        cd.PresentationDone,
        cd.MOUDone
    };
```

EF generated SQL query from the above:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyCity] AS [CompanyCity], 
    [Extent1].[NumberOfEmployees] AS [NumberOfEmployees], 
    [Extent1].[ProspectingScore] AS [ProspectingScore], 
    [Limit1].[PDFResourceLibrary] AS [PDFResourceLibrary], 
    [Limit1].[PresentationDone] AS [PresentationDone], 
    [Limit1].[MOUDone] AS [MOUDone]
    FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[PDFResourceLibrary] AS [PDFResourceLibrary], [Project1].[PresentationDone] AS [PresentationDone], [Project1].[MOUDone] AS [MOUDone]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
            [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [PDFResourceLibrary], 
            [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [PresentationDone], 
            [GroupBy1].[K3] AS [MOUDone]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent2].[PDFResourceLibrary] AS [K1], 
                [Extent2].[PresentationDone] AS [K2], 
                [Extent2].[MOUDone] AS [K3], 
                MAX([Extent2].[CycleDate]) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Cycle] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent2].[CompanyId] = [Extent1].[CompanyId]
                GROUP BY [Extent2].[PDFResourceLibrary], [Extent2].[PresentationDone], [Extent2].[MOUDone]
            )  AS [GroupBy1]
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[ProspectingScore] DESC
```

This should cover the question of how to convert the original SQL query.

But do you really need to follow the original SQL query? According to this requirement:

> many cycles can exist for a company, but I need to grab only the latest cycle by date

it looks more natural to use something like this:

```
var query =
    from co in db.Company
    join cy in db.Cycle on co.CompanyId equals cy.CycleId into cycles
    from cd in cycles.OrderByDescending(cy => cy.CycleDate).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby co.ProspectingScore descending
    select new
    {
        co.CompanyId,
        co.CompanyName,
        co.CompanyCity,
        co.NumberOfEmployees,
        co.ProspectingScore,
        cd.PDFResourceLibrary,
        cd.PresentationDone,
        cd.MOUDone
    };
```

which generates:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyCity] AS [CompanyCity], 
    [Extent1].[NumberOfEmployees] AS [NumberOfEmployees], 
    [Extent1].[ProspectingScore] AS [ProspectingScore], 
    [Limit1].[PDFResourceLibrary] AS [PDFResourceLibrary], 
    [Limit1].[PresentationDone] AS [PresentationDone], 
    [Limit1].[MOUDone] AS [MOUDone]
    FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[PDFResourceLibrary] AS [PDFResourceLibrary], [Project1].[PresentationDone] AS [PresentationDone], [Project1].[MOUDone] AS [MOUDone]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].[CycleDate] AS [CycleDate], 
            [Extent2].[PDFResourceLibrary] AS [PDFResourceLibrary], 
            [Extent2].[PresentationDone] AS [PresentationDone], 
            [Extent2].[MOUDone] AS [MOUDone]
            FROM [dbo].[Cycle] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[CompanyId] = [Extent2].[CycleId]
        )  AS [Project1]
        ORDER BY [Project1].[CycleDate] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[ProspectingScore] DESC
```

Comment: In order to make this code work with PagedList, I need to be able to add a `.ToPagedList()` Lambda expression at the end of it. How can I do this?

Comment: `query.ToPagedList(...)`?

Comment: Still running into issues, updated my original post. Your solution has come very, very close, but I am unable to stuff the results into the viewmodel.